# jQuery empty() , click() and memory management

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, jquery-events

Just wondering how is this managed from the memory point of view.

Let's say I have this HTML page.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="someID"></div>
<div>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
$("#someID").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Now somewhere in my script I need to empty (clear) all the content in `#container`:

```
$("#container").empty();
```

Does this automatically remove/unbind the click event, or do I have to do it myself?

Is this something browser specific?

Comment: This is answered directly in the jQuery documentation for empty()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) method unbinds handlers, and clears all other data stored in `jQuery.cache` for all elements nested within `#container`.

jQuery only binds a single (generic) handler to an element. All other handlers and data are stored in `jQuery.cache`. The data for each element is cross-referenced by a serial number that jQuery puts directly on the DOM node.

So this is a jQuery specific system. The only browser specific concern is how jQuery binds the generic handler, and jQuery takes care of that unbinding as well.

---

*From the docs:*

> *"To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves."*

Comment: I see. so basically when I wanna empty an element, jquery searches for all of his children( in this case #someID) and see if any data or event handlers are attached to them and removes them. am I correct?

Comment: @DouaBeri: Yes. It looks to see if the element has a serial number given by jQuery. If so, that means it must have received some sort of data. It uses that serial number to get the related data from `jQuery.cache`. From there it can tell if there were handlers bound. If so, it unbinds the generic handler, and then simply removes the entry from `jQuery.cache`, which enables whatever data was stored to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for, is..

```
$('something').remove();  /removes element and children

$('something').empty(); // clears children
```

Both would remove all `data` and `events` associated with the removed elements.

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from the child elements before removing the
>   elements themselves.`
>
> If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event
>   handlers (so they can be re-added later), use `.detach()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#container").unbind();`   // Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

`$('something').empty();`    // Clear children.

`$('something').remove();`  // Removes element and children.

Comment: And `$("#container").detach();` // Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM was instead.